# Limit involving normal CDF

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I am struggling to calculate the following linmit

$$ \lim_{\gamma_- ~\to ~-1} \Phi\left(\frac{-\gamma~ \Phi ^{-1}(\alpha) - \Phi ^{-1}(\beta)} {\sqrt{1- \gamma^2}} \right)$$

where $\alpha,\beta \in [0,1]$ and $\phi$ is the normal CDF. I am particularlly interested in the case where $1/2< \alpha, \beta < 1$ even more when $\alpha, \beta \approx 1$.

In the first case we know that $\Phi ^{-1}(\alpha) , \Phi ^{-1}(\beta) >0$ so the limit would be $-\infty$ by my reasoning.

Although I am not sure about it even less in the second case.

Could someone give me a hand with that please?

Comment: Note that $0\leq \Phi(x)\leq 1$.

Comment: an example: $\alpha=\beta=\frac34$ then the limit will be $\frac12$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some heuristical reasoning
$$\frac{-\gamma~ \Phi ^{-1}(\alpha) - \Phi ^{-1}(\beta)} {\sqrt{1- \gamma^2}}
= \frac{-\gamma~ \Phi ^{-1}(\alpha) - \Phi ^{-1}(\alpha)+ \Phi ^{-1}(\alpha)- \Phi ^{-1}(\beta)} {\sqrt{1- \gamma^2}}
= \frac{-(\gamma+1) \Phi ^{-1}(\alpha) + \Phi ^{-1}(\alpha)- \Phi ^{-1}(\beta)} {\sqrt{1- \gamma^2}}
= -\sqrt{\frac{1+\gamma}{1-\gamma}} \Phi ^{-1}(\alpha)
 + \frac{\Phi ^{-1}(\alpha)- \Phi ^{-1}(\beta)} {\sqrt{1- \gamma^2}}
=: f_1(\gamma)+f_2(\gamma)
$$
We always have $\lim_{\gamma ~\to ~-1} f_1(\gamma)=0$ and if $\alpha=\beta$ then  $f_2(\gamma)=0$ and the result is $\Phi(0)=\frac{1}{2}$. If $a\ne b$ we get  $f_2(\gamma) \rightarrow \pm \infty$ and the result will be $\Phi(-\infty)=0$ for $b>a$ and $\Phi(+\infty)=1$ for $b<a$.